# Why multiple WebView can't share the cache?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-webview

I have an app developed with react-native. The react-native-webview and react-navigation plugins are used.

When I opened an interface that contained a webview and then jumped to another interface that contained a webview, I found that they could not share the cache. The static files referenced by the previous page were loaded again on the next page.

But if I redirect the url of the webpage in the same webview, the cache works and everything is normal.

react-native-webview uses the default configuration, and the cache-control for static file requests is normal.

I don't know if the webview performance under android is like this, or is it another problem?

[image]

```
 <WebView
          ref={this.webview}
          source={{uri: url}}
          mixedContentMode="compatibility"
          useWebKit={true}
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
          allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange}
          onLoadStart={this._onLoadStart}
          onLoadEnd={this._onLoadEnd}
          onMessage={this.invoke.listener}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `sharedCookiesEnabled={true}`